# Error for virtualenvwrapper / Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I followed this guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04 and get a error message:[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlMmr.png)

When I try "$ workon name_of_virtual_env" I get ": command not found"

I can't understand from where the problem have come and what the error message mean. 
I tried a bit of experiment and get so far:

- The problem in the last line.
- The file in the last line exist on the specified path.
- The module is installed for python3.
- No other versions of python never have been installed before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting this PATH in my .bashrc:

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=my_path_to_python
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=my_path_to_virtualenv
```

solved my problem.